# Selecting an object from a list of objects, from a DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, linq

Where a `DropDownList` is bound to a list of `job` objects, is the binding direct or is it a separate list altogether? I have been using a LINQ expression to extract a single `job` object from the selection as follows:

```
job selectedJob = (JobList.Single(j => j.JobID == Convert.ToInt32(jobDropDown.SelectedValue)));
```

Is this huge overkill for what I'm trying to do, and is there a shorter/easier/more efficient way of doing it?

*Minor edit: I used `Convert.ToInt32` just in case the ValueMember was converted into a string in the webcontrol assignment. I'm aware it might be unnecessary.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like overkill to me and looks fairly straightforward. The only issue I could see is the use of `.Single()` which will throw an error if no results are found or duplicate results are found. If you're needing to ensure that there is only one result, then using `.Single()` should be fine, although the entire list has to be processed even once a result is found. Using `.FirstOrDefault()` would be better as it will return once the first result is found or return null of none are found.

Comment: Just to clarify, would the following be poor practice?

`job selectedJob = jobDropDown.Find( j => j.Selected == true );`

Comment: Assuming you're using a `List` object, according to the [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,a8a85c5fb1a25488), that should be just as efficient as [FirstOrDefault](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,b7e5965cab68b1cf). Both do about the same thing. The `j.Selected == true` is a bit redundant though. The predicate can just be `j.Selected`.